# CSS: different <li> parent-child backgrounds and sizes

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="menu3" >
 <ul class="cssMenu">   
  <li>
   <a href="#">Parent</a>       
    <ul class="cssMenuA">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Child1</a></span></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Child2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Child3</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

.menu3 {
background: url(../images/menu3.png) no-repeat;
float:left;
width:134px;
height:50px;}

.menu3 a:hover {
background: url(../images/menu3-hover.png) no-repeat;
float:left;
width:134px;
height:50px;}

    ul.cssMenuA ul li { 
        float:left;
        background: #FFA900;
        width: 90px; 
        height:25px; 
        display: inline;            
    }

    ul.cssMenuA ul li a { 
        background: #FFA900;
        width: 90px; 
        height:25px;
        display: block;
        font-family: Arial, Times New Roman, Tahoma;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000000;
    } 

    ul.cssMenuA ul li a:hover{ 
        background: #FFA900;
        width: 90px; 
        height:25px; 
        display: inline;
        font-family: Arial, Times New Roman, Tahoma;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#FFF;
    }
```

I would like to make my **Parent** `ul/li` and **child** `ul/li` to have different, but fixed sizes. I have defined a background image for my Parent item `class="menu3"`, but I want a different non-image Child1, 2 and 3 `class="cssMenuA"`. But the children are using also the image, as the parent item.

*I hope you understand my problem and hope to help me out with this issue. Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where's your CSS?

Comment: Ive added the CSS, its not complete, but should be enough to get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change from `.menu3 a:hover {}` to `.menu3 > li > a:hover` :

```
.menu3 > li > a:hover {
    background: url(../images/menu3-hover.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    width:134px;
    height:50px;
}
```

With this CSS, you'll search for direct `<li>` children, and in those, direct `<a>` children (which means you don't have to care about subchildren `<a>`).

Comment: thank you for your help, it solved the issue with the image! Now there's only one thing left, that is unsolved. Why the `<a>` tag still has a different size in the children's `<li>`? Thank you.

Comment: In the lowest level `<li>`, you've got this rule : `ul.cssMenuA ul li a { width: 90px; }`. In the highest level one, you don't have any rule which set the `<a>` size (well, in fact there's one, but only for the hover state).